# Windows Phone: Can not fit listbox item to the phone screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a listbox which shows string of different length. If the length of the string is greater than the screen width, the rest is not shown on the screen. How can I fit that kind of string to the screen by using listbox ?

Answer (score 1):

Use TextWrapping="Wrap" in you TextBlock to have the text wrap when it hits the width of the control.